# Track shipment document holder within a company

Tags: excel, sharepoint, tracking, file-sharing

Can i use excel to create a list of shipment numbers, and know which user in my company has any shipment document number on his desk?

my thinking is to create (scan from barcodes) a list of shipment numbers i get each morning,  and each user on this shared excel file can access it, and when someone takes one/sone of these shipment document to HIS desk from mine, he'll scan them to some sort of form maybe, that will automatically list HIM as the holder of that document.

just need to know which user has any one of these documents at any given time.

no idea how to approach this.

the company uses sharepoint (which i know nothing of) but i don't want to create multiple items. there are too many and it seems too much.

any help on how to approache this will be appreciated.

somehow i feel the solution is very simple and just escapes me.

edit: to clarify what i need is essentially a list of numbers
and to know which number was scaned last by who
like
so say i scan 66543 and 66770 at 9:05. it will say:
66543 last scanned by John today at 9:05
66770 last scanned by john today at 9:05

then later at 10:50 Mary will take 66770 from me and then it will changed to:
66543 last scanned by John today at 9:05
66770 last scanned by Mary today at 10:55

Comment: Use a network drive instead if you have that. But it won't work reliably. The only way it can work is if each user has a client workbook that when you scan a document will open the master document and add a line and then close it again. But that won't work if two people scan at the same time. You could add a wait function if the workbook is open by someone else. Or you open a text document which you write the whereabouts of each document which will probably work better since it's faster and less chance of a two person at the same time incident. I'd give it a plausible. Depending how many users

Comment: But the question is too broad for us. You need to be more specific with your problems and preferably one or two at the time if they are related.

Comment: well i don't need to scan the entire document.  just the barcode that translates into a number. so say i scan 45432 in the morning into a file that says the last scan of this number was by me. and an hour later someone named sharon takes 45432 into HER desk. i will then ask her to scan the document barcode into the fild again and then the file will show HER as the last holder of this document.

Comment: @TonyM I believe you misunderstood paper document from computer document.